# batch file which creates a new batch file

Tags: batch-file

i need a batch file "master.bat" which on executing creates a new batch file "children.bat" with the given doce on it:
Code is

@echo off

> "pre.txt" (for /f "tokens=3,4" %%a in (
>     'net statistics workstation ^| find "since"'
>   ) do (
>     echo %%a %%b
>   ))
>   exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To create a new batch file containg that code:**

Just `echo` the code and send it into the file you want (`>`)

```
echo @echo off "pre.txt" (for /f "tokens=3,4" %%a in ( 'net statistics workstation ^| find "since"' ) do ( echo %%a %%b )) exit > mybat.bat
```

**To just run that code in a way that works:**

```
for /f "tokens=3,4" %%a in ( 'net statistics workstation ^| find "since"' ) do ( echo %%a %%b >> pre.txt )
```

**Create and run batch file**

```
echo @echo off > children.bat
echo for /f "tokens=3,4" %%%%a in ( 'net statistics workstation ^^^| find "since"' ) do ( echo %%%%a %%%%b ^>^> pre.txt ) >> children.bat && children.bat
```

Comment: i did this but it creates a new bat file "mybat.bat" with no text in it. it creates an empty bat.

Comment: Did you change anything? I just copied and pasted the code above back into a CMD window and ran it from a batch file - both worked as expected

Comment: the file "mybat.bat" should create a new file "pre.txt" on running which is missing in your code

Comment: So you need a batch file to create a file called children.bat that contains the code you posted, and then run that new batch file, which should be creating a text file? Why not just run your code from the original batch file instead of writing it to a new one (children.bat)?

Comment: no dude this is the requirement specifically mentioned by the client

Comment: can this code be modified to add "children.bat" in c:\windows\system32 directory. like if we run mybat.bat it would create children.bat at c:\windows\system32\children.bat

Comment: Yea just put whatever path in front of anywhere that says `children.bat` (provided you have write permissions of course)

Comment: thanx buddy you are a life saviour

Comment: @MohitPal No worries, glad to help. Just be sure to accept the answer with the tick image to help any others that come across this question in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
title Just a sandbox test
color f
:start
cls
set "file=%userprofile%\Desktop\children.bat
(
echo ^@echo off
echo ^"pre.txt^" ^(for /f ^"tokens=3,4^" ^%^%a in ^( ^'net statistics 
workstation ^^^| find echo ^"since^"^' ^) do ^( echo ^%^%a ^%^%b ^)^) exit
) >%file%

::rest of your code goes here I guess
pause
```

Just tested and this will work. Adding ^ before characters that will normally conflict with the syntax will force the script to ignore it. :)

Ps. Sorry it's a bit late lol